# Get the smallest number of array, instead of sum using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I'm trying to use Lodash in order to extract the data from JSON with prices of each room type during the month for a particular hotel in booking.

In the example below, as a result I get an average price of all booking options (number of persons, with/without breakfast, etc) for each room type. Instead I need to get only the cheapest booking options for each room type.

How do I do that? Is it possible to get only the smallest number in variantData for each room type?

An example of a JSON I'm trying to extract: https://pastebin.com/Ak0PPqfp

```
const prices = _.map(months, (monthData, monthNumber) => {
    const monthName = monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    const types = _.groupBy(_.flatten(monthData.map(d => d['Room_type'])), 'Apartment Title');
    const result = _.map(types, (typeData, typeName) => {
        const variants = _.flatten(typeData.map((t) => _.flatten(t['variants'])));
        const prices = _.map(_.groupBy(variants, 'Description'), (variantData, variantDescr) => {
            return {
                'Average price': Math.round(variantData.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur['Price'], 0) / variantData.length),
            };
        })
        return {
            'Type': typeName,
            'Variants': prices,
        };
    });
    return {
        'Mongth': monthName,
        'Prices': result,
    };
});
```

Comment: instead of 

` 'Average price': Math.round(variantData.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur['Price'], 0) / variantData.length),`
            };

try 
 'cheapest price: variantData.reduce((acc, cur) => acc < cur['Price']?acc:cur['Price'], 0) ,
            };

Answer (score 0):

The min() method returns the lowest value in an array. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-min-method/

So, in your case something like:

```
return {
    'Lowest Price':_.min(prices);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several lodash methods that can help you write a simpler, and more readable code:

1. `_.minBy()` to get the object with the minimum value
2. `_.sumBy()` to get the sum of multiple objects, and then you can get the average by dividing the sum with the length of the array
3. `_.flatMap()` instead of `_.flatten(_.map())`

```js
const prices = _.map(months, (monthData, monthNumber) => {
  const monthName = ''; // monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
  const types = _.groupBy(_.flatMap(monthData, 'Room_Type'), 'Room_Title');
  const result = _.map(types, (typeData, typeName) => {
    const variants = _.flatMap(typeData, 'variants');
    const prices = _.map(_.groupBy(variants, 'Description'), (variantData, variantDescr) => {
      return {
        'Average price': _.sumBy(variantData, 'Price') / variantData.length,
        'Minimum price': _.minBy(variantData, 'Price').Price
      };
    })
    return {
      'Type': typeName,
      'Variants': prices,
    };
  });
  return {
    'Mongth': monthName,
    'Prices': result,
  };
});

console.log(prices);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  const months = [[{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-18","Check_Out":"2021-12-19","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":849,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":853,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":858,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=18&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=19&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-19","Check_Out":"2021-12-20","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":849,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":853,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":858,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=19&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=20&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-20","Check_Out":"2021-12-21","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":849,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":853,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":858,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=20&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=21&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-22","Check_Out":"2021-12-23","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":849,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":853,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":858,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=22&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=23&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-21","Check_Out":"2021-12-22","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":429,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":425,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":849,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":853,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":858,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=21&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=22&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-23","Check_Out":"2021-12-24","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=23&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=24&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-24","Check_Out":"2021-12-25","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=24&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=25&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-25","Check_Out":"2021-12-26","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=25&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=26&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-26","Check_Out":"2021-12-27","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=26&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=27&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-27","Check_Out":"2021-12-28","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=27&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=28&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-28","Check_Out":"2021-12-29","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=28&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=29&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-29","Check_Out":"2021-12-30","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=29&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-31","Check_Out":"2022-1-1","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=31&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=1&checkout_year_month=2022-1&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2021-12-30","Check_Out":"2021-12-31","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=30&checkin_year_month=2021-12&checkout_monthday=31&checkout_year_month=2021-12&selected_currency=EUR"},{"Hotel_Title":"Apartments\nHONEST APARTMENTS","Check_In":"2022-1-1","Check_Out":"2022-1-2","Room_Type":[{"Room_Title":"Junior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":169,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":173,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Apartment - Ground Floor","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2}]},{"Room_Title":"Superior Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":4},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":4}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort Wall Bed","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Studio Comfort","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":0,"Rooms_Left":8}]},{"Room_Title":"Loft Apartment","variants":[{"Price":170,"Description":"","Occupancy":2,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":174,"Description":"","Occupancy":3,"Rooms_Left":2},{"Price":179,"Description":"","Occupancy":4,"Rooms_Left":2}]}],"url":"https://www.booking.com/hotel/cz/honest-apartments.en-gb.html?checkin_monthday=1&checkin_year_month=2022-1&checkout_monthday=2&checkout_year_month=2022-1&selected_currency=EUR"}]]
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
What should I do If I need an average price of all minimum prices per each type during the month?

Comment: Do a sum of all minimum prices in the month, and divide by the length of types.